# Windows 8.1 kiosk (assigned access) with IE in kiosk mode iexplore.exe -k

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-8.1, kiosk

I am using windows 8.1 "assigned access" (kiosk mode) - and the selected app is Internet Explorer.

Everything works as is, so when the kiosk user boots up, IE opens in metro style. All very nice, but the user still has access to the address bar, so ultimately I would like to open IE but with the switch -k so IE itself is in kiosk mode.

Any advice on how to go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been a little bit since you opened this, but I'd thought I'd share.
I just used group policy to set the default shell to IE and included the switch in the filepath.
So...

> Run > gpedit.msc > User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Custom User Interface

Enable the policy and set the value to *filepath*\iexplore.exe -k

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. It's not 100% perfect, since I needed explorer.exe and other processes running in the background. But it's a step in the right direction for the ever elusive kiosk mode.